# C# Problems with Reading Standard Output

Tags: c#, standards

This ones got me stumped. So I'm making a program in C# to provide a GUI frontend for the Terraria Server. I have tried several methods but I always get the same problem.
First I start the process using System.Diagnostic.
Then I have tried several things, such as asynchronously reading the console output using BeginOutputReadLine or creating a Background worker to execute the following:

```
        while (!terrariaProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            consoleOutput.Items.Add(terrariaProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
```

But the output always comes out muddled.
Example
It should be: (How it looks if I use cmd to execute it)

```
Terraria Server v1.0.6.1
Choose World: 
1       Test
n       New World
d <number>  Delete World
>>n
Choose size:
1       Small
2       Medium
3       Large
>>3
Enter World Name:
>>Hello World
```

However my program reads it as:

```
Terraria Server v1.0.6.1
1       Test
n       New World
d <number>  Delete World
>>n
Choose World: Terraria Server v1.0.6.1
1       Small
2       Medium
3       Large
>>3
Choose size: Terraria Server v1.0.6.1
>>Hello World
```

It does this no matter what method I use. Can someone help please? Am I being an idiot (again)?

EDIT:
On Jon's request I have made a small console application to try to do the same thing. I am having some trouble checking for console input from within a loop so I can only test up to the first prompt but it still seems broken.
My code:

```
    Process terrariaProcess;
    terrariaProcess = new Process();
    terrariaProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "TerrariaServer.exe";
    terrariaProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    terrariaProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    terrariaProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    terrariaProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    terrariaProcess.Start();
    while (!terrariaProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(terrariaProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    }
```

The result output:

```
Terraria Server v1.0.6.1
1       Test
n       New World
d <number>  Delete World
```

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is with how you're displaying the output?

Comment: I doubt it. Every line of output I get I add to a ListBox. I'll try adding them to a string though, hang on a sec

Comment: BTW, do you spend your entire life hovering at your keyboard looking at this site? Because you always answer my questions. (And it always turns out I was being an idiot)

Comment: Well I just tried adding it to a TextBox and there was no difference. I don't think I've exactly used the best coding practices though. Calling CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; just looks like it's begging for trouble to me.

Comment: I'll see what happens when I make it thread safe

Comment: I would try writing a short but complete program which just launches the process from a *console* app, and see what happens. Then you can post the whole of your code.

Comment: Ok. Will do. moreletters

Comment: YoshieMaster Jon Skeet if you ain't seen yet is a Software Engineer at Google ,all i can say man if you got no one to trust in this world of Software Development ,Jon is the right man to trust in that case .

Comment: Alright, done that. Should I edit my original post to have the code?

Comment: Wow, thanks for letting me know Cody, I feel honoured to have Jon working on my small problems. I feel so special! (Emotion sphere self test complete)

Comment: I'll edit the Original Post now

Answer (score 0):

Call the function `Console.Out.Flush();`

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of the Terraria Server.